# Questions on OAuth 2 server in ASP.NET Web Api

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2

Currently, I think *my understanding* of OAuth and how it it is implemented in ASP.NET Web Api is flawed.

1) I keep seeing OAuth described as a server (i.e. the OAuth server). Is the OAuth implementation by a Microsoft a separate server with a different port or is it just referred to as a server even though it is self contained within the API project?

2) Is OWIN separate from OAuth or are the two linked such that they must be used together?

3) How does an OAuth v2 server keep track of tokens that have been revoked or have expired? Does the OAuth component have a database that keeps track of the tokens that it issues? If so, what type of database is it?

I have been reading the tutorials by [Taiseer Joudeh from bitoftech.net](http://bitoftech.net/) but I think I am missing some of the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my responses:

1. You can implement the server as a stand alone authorization server or you can implement it together with the resource server. The Visual Studio template brings you both servers together, but you can separate them. Tutorials from Taiseer Joudeh will guide you very well, they did in my case.
2. OAuth 2.0 is an authorization framework, as said in its [definition document](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749). And [OWIN](http://owin.org/) stands for Open Web Interface for .NET. Both of them are different things, but Microsoft decided to do an implementation of OAuth 2.0 protocol using OWIN middlewares architecture. Then the easiest way to develop OAuth 2.0 servers in ASP.NET is using `Microsoft.Owin.Security.*` libraries implemented by Microsoft.
3. The OAuth 2.0 protocol does not talk about keeping track of expired or revoked tokens, you could implement if you want, but you only could do if the authorization and resource servers are both the same, and then you will need to access to database to check the token for each request, that it is not necessary. If the resource server is separated from the authorization server it has no direct access to the authorization server database. Normally you don't do that. The expiration check of the token is something that the `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth` library makes for you. If a token received by the resource server has expired, the library responds with a 401 - Unauthorized response.
   To make possible that the resource server can decrypt the token, you only need to set the same machine key in both servers' web.config file.
   To avoid to have long lived access tokens you could set short access token timespan and implement refresh token. In this case, you could save refresh tokens in database and you can implement some method to revoke them.
   Refresh tokens and its revokation are implemented in Taiseer Joudeh blog posts too.

I hope my explanations are clear and can help you. Please tell me if you have any other doubts.

Comment: These are very helpful. Thank you

Comment: So I think I was completely overestimating what the OAuth server was doing  Are you saying that that refresh tokens are not generated automatically by the middleware, but that we as developers have to take care of storing the original token and then sending out refresh tokens?

Comment: Yes, I am. As said in [`OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions.RefreshTokenProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.oauth.oauthauthorizationserveroptions.refreshtokenprovider(v=vs.113).aspx) property documentation, *if not provided the authorization server will not return refresh tokens*.

Comment: And as explained in `OAuth 2.0` protocol defitinition *issuing a [refresh token](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#page-10) is optional at the discretion of the authorization server.  If the authorization server issues a refresh token, it is included when issuing an access token*, and as for access tokens, you can store in database or simply decrypt it when received and use the information contained in it. The way Taiseer Joudeh implemented refresh tokens let the authorization server administrator invalidate a refresh token if it is necessary for any reason.

Comment: Thanks so much Jamuro!